# Issue on Android Devices while looping sounds using playBackgroundMusic Method in Cocos2d-x CocosDenshion

Tags: android, cocos2d-x

I am using the `playBackgroundMusic()` method to play my music files.
I have set the loop parameter to true.
I have tried the following formats:

- .wav
- .ogg
- .mp3
- .mp4
- .m4a

The problem is that the file is looping, but it is not looping seamlessly on android devices.
It loops perfectly well on iphone anf ipad.

Every-time the file end is reached, there is a small gap and then it plays again.
The gap is about a fraction of a second, but still noticeable.

I have tried 5-6 different sounds and also changed the formats. No Luck!!

I have also build the "Tests" project that comes with the cocos2d-x library, on my android device and played the CocosDenshion Test.
It seems that even that one is having a problem with seamless looping.

Has anyone tried this??
I would really appreciate if any one pitches in with their idea. :)

If I use `playEffect()`, then the sound loops, but I do not want to use playEffect for playing music files.

NOTE :- I am using `cocos2d-x 1.0.1-x-0.11.0` version.
Which is the latest.

Comment: Try and update your project with Cocos2d-2.0-x-2.0.3 you wont get this issue... it has been resolved in bug fix in 2.0

Comment: on which android device you trying this ?

Answer (score 1):

I am new in stackoverflow.
I am using cocos2d-x 3.1 and following code is working perfectly fine:

```
CocosDenshion::SimpleAudioEngine::sharedEngine()->playBackgroundMusic("music.ogg", true);
```

Try to port your code to newer version of cocos2d-x.
I hope it helps